# Change the datasource in a report Devexpress WPF Xtrareports

Tags: wpf, devexpress

I have a report in Devexpress that is assigned to a certain Datasource and I need to change it to a different Datasource. I want to do this without having to put all the fields back into the report. To help me with this I copied all of my tables and stored procedures to the new Database. Is there a way to do this? This report is going to multiple clients that each have their own naming convention so I would need to be able to change it dynamically. Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can comfortably change the connection string and everything should work. This also depends on how you are accessing your data. If you are using standard datasets or some other ORM tool then this should work so long as you have exposed the connection string in your config file.